# ProxMox OpenVSwitch with Guest pfSense Firewall

Tags: networking, bridge, proxmox

Here's what I'm trying to setup:

Proxmox will be top-level main machine that will have 16x ethernet ports.

I want to install pfSense as guest here and make it main gateway, firewall and where VLANs of the rest of the network will be defined.

I will connect 10 separate machines to these ethernet ports on ProxMox server and want to "bridge"? them to pfSense guest including WAN, LAN and other vLANs ProxMox itself will be only manageable and admin interface only accessible through a Vlan that will be assigned to another guest VM running inside ProxMox.

Is this doable? If yes, can someone explain for I can do that? Like how I can do bridging with OVS here?